# Find word(s) right after a particular substring in Python

Tags: python, regex

```
text = "This text is not important but name of teacher, name of dog and name of cat is very interesting"
```

And I need add words next to "name of" in a list

```
match = [teacher, dog, cat]
```

Comment: Ok, and what have your attempts resulted in?

Comment: Please improve your question quality. You can find more tips in: [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) pages.

Answer (score 5):

Using `re.findall` from the `re` module (`import re` first):

```
In [1033]: re.findall('(?<=name of )\w+', text)
Out[1033]: ['teacher', 'dog', 'cat']
```

---

```
'(?<=name of )\w+'
```

Uses a lookbehind of fixed width, extracting text that follows `'name of '`.

Alternatively, a slightly more bulletproof regex would be: `'(?:name\s+of\s+)(\w+)'` (taking into account varying space characters).

Comment: Nitpick: `(?:name of\s+)(\w+)` would probably be better than a lookbehind in case there is more than one space between the 'prefix' and the word itself.